# Play Framework - Getting Session Data in Views

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

How can I get session data in views in Play Framework 2.3.x?

I used to use `session.get("sessionName")` but now I get `not found: value session` when I try to use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ought to pass all mandatory variables to a view. In order to get access to the session you should declare it as parameter of your template.

```
@(title:String)(implicit session: Session)

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @session.get("sessionname")
    </body>
</html>
```

Using *implicit* will allow you to avoid passing the session explicitly from a controller.

```
def index = Action { implicit req =>
  Ok(views.html.index("Page Title"))
}
```